# How do I get the task ids associated with a particular service

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ecs

When I call `DescribeServies` I am expecting an array of tasks arn or ids of tasks associated with my service. However that is not the case, unless I inspect the `events` object:

```
Events: [
        {
          CreatedAt: 2020-07-03 03:57:56 +0000 UTC,
          Id: "af62a356-2ab7-4b18-b51c-718bef02901c",
          Message: "(service 0271a020-aa1e-4b72-a57a-6d91c5f463e4) has reached a steady state."
        },
        {
          CreatedAt: 2020-07-03 03:57:44 +0000 UTC,
          Id: "de2a4fad-8ea8-419d-8493-8c7cb5406afb",
          Message: "(service 0271a020-aa1e-4b72-a57a-6d91c5f463e4) has stopped 1 running tasks: (task 1f92882b-72d0-490b-aa03-18fd32edb2e8)."
        },
        {
          CreatedAt: 2020-07-03 01:35:09 +0000 UTC,
          Id: "bd8da7f5-9bb1-4d23-b416-f79678b487a8",
          Message: "(service 0271a020-aa1e-4b72-a57a-6d91c5f463e4) has reached a steady state."
        },
        {
          CreatedAt: 2020-07-03 01:34:40 +0000 UTC,
          Id: "da05f6a0-4163-4d93-b7af-22297d307620",
          Message: "(service 0271a020-aa1e-4b72-a57a-6d91c5f463e4) has started 1 tasks: (task e132a2a7-ad49-4436-88cb-07b2ce399dd2)."
        },
        {
          CreatedAt: 2020-07-02 14:29:21 +0000 UTC,
          Id: "cb56a4ff-de6a-402f-aaa5-377bf236b00a",
          Message: "(service 0271a020-aa1e-4b72-a57a-6d91c5f463e4) has started 1 tasks: (task e69ca53b-7b5c-4c7d-aed2-b28d9261b111)."
        }
      ]
```

Which as you can see it is quite tricky to extract the task id

**My end goal is to programmatically get the IP of the instance where the service has been deployed**

My current clunky solution: (Errors handling is omitted for brevity)

```golang
    servicesResponse, _ := s.ecsClient.DescribeServices(describeServicesParams)


    var taskId string
    for _, serviceEvent := range servicesResponse.Services[0].Events {

        if strings.Contains(*serviceEvent.Message, "has stopped 1 running tasks") {
            break
        }

        if strings.Contains(*serviceEvent.Message, "has started 1 tasks") {
            found := strings.Split(*serviceEvent.Message, "has started 1 tasks: (task ")[1]
            taskId = strings.Replace(found, ").", "", -1)
            break
        }
    }
    log.Info("taskId", taskId)
```

After that I call `DescribeTasks` to get the `containerInstanceArn` and with that I call `DescribeInstances`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DescribeTasks` as you noted, its not very well suited to get the tasks IDs in a service.

Normally, to get the lists of tasks in a service you would use [ListTasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ListTasks.html) call. For the call you can specify the service name of interest:

> serviceName: The name of the service with which to filter the ListTasks results. Specifying a serviceName limits the results to **tasks that belong to that service**.

The `ListTasks` will give you `taskArns` which in turn can be used in [DescribeTasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTasks.html) to get tasks [details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_Task.html).

The task id is a part of its `arn`, so if you only want ids, you can extract them from the arns.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I might have missed that you can specify the `serviceName`

Comment: @Madeo No problem. Glad it helped:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example that is base on AWS-CLI, you can convert that accordingly on the desired language.

- It fetches all task for service
- Get container instance and trap EC2_ID
- Get IP of Ec2
  It will exactly do what you are looking for

> **My end goal is to programmatically get the IP of the instance where the service has been deployed**

```
#!/bin/bash
CLUSTER_NAME="mycluster"
SERVICE_NAME="app-service"
REGION="us-west-2"

echo "[INFO] Fetching tasks list for Cluster: $CLUSTER_NAME and Service: $SERVICE_NAME"
TASKS_ARN=($(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME  --service $SERVICE_NAME --query 'taskArns[]' --output text))

for task in ${!TASKS_ARN[@]}; do
container_instances=$(aws ecs describe-tasks     --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME  --tasks ${TASKS_ARN[$task]} --query 'tasks[].containerInstanceArn' --output text)
ec2_instance_id=$(aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --container-instances $container_instances --region $REGION --query 'containerInstances[*].ec2InstanceId' --output text)
ec2_ip=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $ec2_instance_id --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress' --output text)
echo "[INFO] Task having ARN ${TASKS_ARN[$task]} runnng on EC2 machine having IP: $ec2_ip"
echo "[INFO] Fetchec completed  for task number $(($task+1)) out of ${#TASKS_ARN[@]},having Task ARN: ${TASKS_ARN[$task]}"
done
```

[get_instance_ip_for_ecs_service.sh](https://gist.github.com/Adiii717/bbfdfaad6e2930bc1ee1003587bbb908)